# Do I have to _setDomainName in Google Analytics for each Top-level Domain I am tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, multiple-domains

I have 3 domains pointing to the same website, with no redirects, so domain1.com, domain2.com and domain3.com show the same content and do not redirect between each other.

If I want to track all domains, do I have to check `Multiple top-level domains` in the "What you are tracking" section and add this the following for each domain

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain1.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain2.com']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain3.com']);
```

Or is it enough to just set it for domain1.com?
Or maybe the regular tracking code under "A single domain" will do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use multiple `_setDomainName` in a tracking code, only the last will be used.

`_setDomainName` "attribute" the cookies to a domain. If you use `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain1.com']);` only domain1.com can use the cookie.

So you need to use :

- `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain1.com']);` alone on domain1.com
- `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain2.com']);` alone on domain2.com
- `_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain3.com']);` alone on domain".com

Comment: I don't understand something - how will google know that domain2.com belongs to me? when I open google analytics account, I will define my site to be domain1.com, and then I will put the same google ID accross all the 3 mentioned domains. There is no place where the other 2 domains are registered. For example, what stops me from putting to my domain1.com the Analytics ID of stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Nothing stops you to do that. But : 1) stackoverflow can easily filter there stats to only include there domain, 2) Analytics team can ban your domain from the system.